# Loading Excel without Add Ins

Tags: excel, vba

All,

I wrote a spreadsheet application which users load it by doubleclicking an icon I provide them. The problem is users have a lot of addins which slow Excel down. How can someone load Excel using command line switches to disable all add-ins ? The question applies to both Excel 2003 and Excel 2007.

Many Thanks,

MK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I have since found the way of doing it:

"Excel /automation"

Also using JavaScript:

```
var workingDirectory = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").CurrentDirectory;
var x = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
x.Visible = -1;
x.Interactive = -1;
x.Workbooks.Add();
```

Rgds,

MK